# How do I remove the Chrome menu button?

Tags: chrome-for-android

It appeared in Chrome 40 and occupies precious space in the address bar.

I'm using a Samsung phone, which already has a menu button.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to uninstall and disable updates in settings > application manager > all.  As chrome is a system app in Samsung,  to completely uninstall it you would probably need root permission and "uninstall system apps" from Google Play.

Comment: That reverts back Android to an old and insecure Chrome release. It doesn't solve the issue for the release mentioned in question.